# SDL 2.0 Can I run it not in main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl

I use Boost Threads and SDL 1.2 now. I wonder if I would use SDL 2.* will I be able to run it not from main  thread (on bouth windows and linux)?

Answer (score 3):

From a purely technical standpoint, there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to. I haven't used Boost Threads or SDL 2.*, however I have used SDL 1.2, SDL Threads, Windows Threads, and pthread. On Windows, the only snag I've run in to is that the thread that creates the SDL window **has** to be the thread that handles events. Other than that, there isn't any issues that I've run in to. I don't know if the same holds for Linux, because I always get my code working on Windows before porting it.

Comment: ` the SDL window has to be the thread that handles events. ` that is my main question - can window it be made and events handeled not from  main thread?

Comment: No. The thread that spawns the Window absolutely must be the thread that grabs events.

Comment: If you call `SDL_CreateWindow()` in a thread, (let's call it thread `X`) then you can only call `SDL_PollEvent()` from within thread `X`. If you try calling `SDL_PollEvent()` from thread `Y`, you won't receive any events.